# Appending PDF to Existing PDF in cold fusion 11

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, pdf-generation

I am using Cold fusion 11.

I want to append a PDF to an existing PDF and want to generate approximately 30 pages like this e.g. I have a PDF with with 20 pages and I want to append 5 more pages to it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has shown no effort to solve the problem on his own.

Comment: Did you search first? The first result from google for "coldfusion merge pdf" [Adobe ColdFusion 9 * Merging PDF documents](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-798f.html).

Comment: @Dan Bracuk We have used merge  method in cfpdf tag.We need a pdf with 1000 pages and its size is approx 1  .5 GB.We  incresed heap space also. But it did nothing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cfpdf` tag with `merge` as action to accomplish it.Like this

```
<cfpdf action="merge" destination="finalMergedPDF.pdf" overwrite="yes"> 
    <cfpdfparam source="pdf_20_pages.pdf"> 
    <cfpdfparam source="pdf_5_pages.pdf"> 
</cfpdf>
```

You can also specify specific pages or range of pages while merging pdf files in `cfpdfparam`. Like this.

```
<cfpdfparam source="file3.pdf" pages="10-20">
<cfpdfparam source="file4.pdf" pages="25,35,42">
```

[Refer this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-798f.html)